# Regex matching Google Cache url (matching entire href parameter when it contains a word)

Tags: html, regex

*Disclaimer: I know that html and regex should not stand together, but this is an exceptional case.*

I need to parse Google Search results and extract cache urls. I have this in the page:

```
<a href="/url?q=http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:
gsNKb7ku3ewJ:somedata&ei=MyIIUtrZAcPX7AaVzIHwDg&amp;ved=0CB8QIDAC&amp;usg
=AFQjCNGcnWfdzQiTKwyAMmI-M-xzxII5Ag">Cached</a>
```

I tried simple stuff like: `href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)` but it is not what I need. I want to extract a single parameter (**q**) from the *href*. I need to get:

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:gsNKb7ku3ewJ:somedata
```

So everything between "url?q=" and first "&", when the contents contain word "webcache" in it.

Comment: This is not an exceptional case as far as I can tell. Are you doing this with javascript or something else?

Comment: `(?<=href=[\'"]?/url\?q=)[^&\'">]+(?=&)` Might do the trick?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Python..

Comment: Why not use a DOM parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your language supports positive look-behinds:

```
(?<=q=).*?(?=[&"])
```

Otherwise match group `\1` with this expression:

```
(?:q=)(.*?)(?=[&"])
```

---

Explanation:

- `.*?` is the body of our expression.  Just match everything, but don't be greedy!
- `(?<=q=)` is a positive look-behind, which says "q=" should come before the match
- `(?=[&"])` is a positive look ahead, which says "either & or a quote should come after the match"

Because we make it not greedy with the `?`, it'll stop at the first quote or ampersand.  Otherwise it'd match all of the way to the closing quote.

Answer (score 1):

Use a look behind before, and a look ahead at the end to assert the surrounding text, and include the keyword in the regex:

```
(?<=url\?q=)[^&]*webcache[^&]*(?=&)
```

Using `[^&]*` ensures that the keyword occurs before an & - within the target string.